# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name abcODBC1 is not bound in this Context at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingConte xt.java:770)

Tags: java, connection, pooling

I'm trying to use Ms Access to test out Connection Pooling but to no avail.And I have read through similar problems at Stackoverflow and elsewhere but still can't resolve the problem.

Here's the error code from Tomcat:

```
    javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name PracticalODBC1 is not bound in this     Context
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:137)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at ProcessRegistration.init(ProcessRegistration.java:37)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:809)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Here's my context.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<Context>
<!-- Specify a JDBC datasource -->
<Resource name="jdbc/odbc:PracticalODBC1" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="com.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"
    url="jdbc:odbc://localhost:3306/pract1"
    maxActive="10" maxIdle="4" />
```

And my servlet:

And my DoPost Servlet:

```
public class ProcessRegistration extends HttpServlet {

private DataSource dataSource;
private Connection conn;
private Statement stmt;
DataSource pool;

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {

    try {
        // Get DataSource
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        pool = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/PracticalODBC1");
        if (pool == null) {
            throw new ServletException("Unknown DataSource 'jdbc/PracticalODBC1'");
        }
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    stmt = null;

  try {
        conn = pool.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

   // inserting records into database
   -----
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(ProcessRegistration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,   null,ex);
     } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
                rs = null;
            }
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
                stmt = null;
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
                conn = null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Servlet records", e);
        }
     }
     out.close();
```

MySQL Connector jar is already placed in the lib.

Hope someone can kindly advise me what went wrong.

Comment: have you tried with:
`<Resource name="jdbc/PracticalODBC1"... />`
And
`pool = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/PracticalODBC1")`

Comment: Still de same error message even if I removed odbc in Resource name. :(